# How to modify the date column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000, Date Column Datatype is varchar...

In my table date column values are like:

```
2009/01/31
2009/02/00
2009/02/01....
2009/03/31
2009/04/00
2009/04/01.... so on...,
```

I want to display 2009/01/31 instead of 2009/02/00, If date is 2009/02/00 it should display previous date.

How to make a query for this condition?

Comment: Is is stored that way as CSV in a text column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about try this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT '2009/01/31'
INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT '2009/02/00'

SELECT * FROM @Table

SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(Val, 1, 8) + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Val, 9, 2) = '00' THEN '01' ELSE SUBSTRING(Val, 9, 2) END AS DATETIME) + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Val, 9, 2) = '00' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    @Table
```

Check if the last chars is 00, then set to 01 and add -1

Comment: is that not what was specified?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I didn't see the fact that there are dates with 00 as the day part.

I whipped up this brute force way.

I'm sure there are optimizations that can be applied, but this should give you a starting point.

```
select dateadd(dd, -1, convert(datetime, case when substring(Reverse(@WeirdDate), 1, 2) = '00' then reverse('1' + substring(Reverse(@WeirdDate), 2, len(@WeirdDate) - 1)) else @WeirdDate end, 101))
```

replace the @WeirdDate with the column name, and it seems to work

```
declare @WeirdDate varchar(10)
set @WeirdDate = '2009/04/00'
select dateadd(dd, -1, convert(datetime, case when substring(Reverse(@WeirdDate), 1, 2) = '00' then reverse('1' + substring(Reverse(@WeirdDate), 2, len(@WeirdDate) - 1)) else @WeirdDate end, 101))

set @WeirdDate = '2009/04/03'
select dateadd(dd, -1, convert(datetime, case when substring(Reverse(@WeirdDate), 1, 2) = '00' then reverse('1' + substring(Reverse(@WeirdDate), 2, len(@WeirdDate) - 1)) else @WeirdDate end, 101))

set @WeirdDate = '2009/01/00'
select dateadd(dd, -1, convert(datetime, case when substring(Reverse(@WeirdDate), 1, 2) = '00' then reverse('1' + substring(Reverse(@WeirdDate), 2, len(@WeirdDate) - 1)) else @WeirdDate end, 101))
```

Comment: Please could you help me out with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254801/how-to-force-web-api-to-return-the-underlying-int-value-of-a-enum

Answer (score 0):

To show the valid dates is pretty easy:

```
SELECT  
   CASE ISDATE(datecolumn) 
     WHEN 1 THEN CAST(datecolumn AS DATETIME) 
     ELSE NULL 
   END  AS 'DateValue'
FROM
  dbo.YourTable
```

But handling the invalid dates like '2009/02/00' is a bit trickier.....

But since you already seem to have the previous date (2009/01/31) - couldn't you just ignore the invalid dates???

```
SELECT  
   CAST(datecolumn AS DATETIME) 
FROM
   dbo.YourTable
WHERE
   ISDATE(datecolumn) = 1
```

Marc